# VB: Calcute mean/average for udt array

Tags: vb6, average, mean

I have an array of a struct

```
Private Type udtSingle
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim Value As Single
end Type

Private m(2) As udtSingle
```

Let's say the array is filled like this:

```
m(0).Count = 5
m(0).Value = 100
m(1).Value = 1
m(1).Count = 10
```

You can see that we have 5*100 and 1*10.

What would be the best way to calcuate the average?

```
for i as integer = 0 to m.upperbound()
     cAll += m(i).Count * m(i).Value
     iCount+=m(i).Count
next i

dim average as currency
average = cAll / iCount
```

That would work, but I have really many .Count and high .Value, and I am afraid of an overflow.

What else could I do, please?

If the array gets really huge, I will get an overflow anyway. Can I not calculate the average anew within the for-next-statement? I guess so, but I can think of an elegant solution.

ps: Yes, I know, the code is kind of pseudo-code...

Comment: VB.Net doesn't support `Type` declarations anymore. It's `structure` now. Are you using vb.net?

Comment: I am using VB6. But I thought that the reply can be in .NET, and I can translate it to VB6, unless somebody suggests using .NETs greater capabilities to hold huge numbers.

Comment: I'd suggested to use LINQ anyway - which you can not translate back to vb6 of course. Also vb.net doesnt have a problem anyway, since it assigns `single` to the result of the multiplication, which can hold quite some large numbers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `cAll` as `Double` to avoid an overflow.

```
Dim cAll as Double
```

and then

```
cAll += Convert.ToDouble(m(i).Count) * Convert.ToDouble(m(i).Value)
```

Double range is up to approximately ±1.7 × 10^308.

Comment: That would not help. I have updated my post to make it more clear.

Comment: Why? Can't really see that but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I wanted to get away from calculation the average after the for-next-statement. I would like to calculate it after each for if possible. Btw, I am working with VB6 where variables can not hold really huge amounts of data, unlike VB.NET.

Comment: VB6 double max value is 1.79E+308, you think your need more than that?